# Using Homestead Web Services - I am not able to move a PHP script into the server file manager? (Error 0x39)

Tags: php, html, web, error-handling, homestead

I am currently constructing a website for a company in which they use Homestead for web hosting. I have successfully uploaded my "html, css, and javascript," files, however when trying to upload my .php script, I am given this message:

"Oops! Your upload failed due to a network or server issue. Try uploading again, and if it doesn't work, call us at: 1-800-710-1998 (Error Code: 0x39)"

Any suggestions why this may be the case?

Further information: (php script name: contact.php) (Size: 1KB)

Comment: Since this is not a Homestead-specific platform and `0x39` appears to be their internal error code, I'm not sure this is the right place for this question. The error already says "call us at: 1-800-710-1998", so did you try calling them?

Comment: In case you can't call a US toll-free number: Their international phone number would be `+1 214-388-2053` (not toll-free though).

Comment: Ok perfect thank you, I suppose I was more curious whether my work-flow was flawed before calling, however if uploading directly to the file manager with my php script is correct, then I will give them a call to try and resolve the issue.

Comment: Uploading a file sounds like a normal thing to do, and since you said it works with the other files (and especially when it works with the same file in their file manager), I don't see how you could be doing something wrong there.

Comment: After calling I have discovered that Homestead does not support .php files, which is ridiculous for what they charge. Thank you for the quick response! @CherryDT